# How much does Canadian skilled worker immigration cost?

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry

I want to know the total cost of immigration for a skilled worker to Canada.

Answer (score 2):

Various fees are [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/fees/fees.asp)

**For Express Entry (or other "economic class"-based visas) application:** $550

For a spouse/partner: $550

For dependents under 19 (or disabled dependants over 18): $150

**Permanent resident fee for principal applicant or spouse/partner:** $490

Dependents: free

You will also need to pay third-party companies or agencies for these:

> c) Other fees. You may have to pay fees to third parties for:
>
> - language testing,
> - Educational Credential Assessments,
> - your medical exam,
> - police checks/clearances and certificates, and
> - translation of documents.

Note: I think you also need to have money to support yourself (and family) for some period of time when you enter the country too. [Here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/funds.asp) it is. The amount changes every year. The money cannot be borrowed.

```
Number of Family Members   Funds Required (in Canadian dollars)
1                          $12,164
2                          $15,143
3                          $18,617
4                          $22,603
5                          $25,636
6                          $28,913
7 or more                  $32,191
```

Comment: Can I borrow this money from friends and family?

Comment: It says no,  but possibly you could get away with it if you had the money in your account for over a year before applying.